# Parsing Newegg website for price

Tags: php, laravel, phpquery, goutte

I'm trying to get the price for the following product 
http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16822236715.

Using just jQuery, the following code is working and gives me the value before preprocessing

```
jQuery('.grpPrimary div[style = "display: block;"] .price-current').text()
```

I'm trying to do the same using Goutte and Laravel:

```
$client = new Client();
$crawler = $client->request('GET', 'http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16822236715');
$crawler = $crawler->filter('.grpPrimary div[style = "display: block;"] .price-current' )->each(function ($node) { 
ECHO  $node->text()."\n";});
```

And I'm not getting the price value, I tried to select its parent divs but the price value is not being shown in any of them. It's the same with phpquery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't tkink this is a good approach, just by exploring the returned HTML, I've seen that there is this small JS :

```
  var utag_data = {
  page_breadcrumb:'Home &gt; Components &gt; Hard Drives &gt; Desktop External Hard Drives &gt; Western Digital &gt; Item#:9SIA29P2YK5768',
        page_tab_name:'Components',
        product_category_id:['15'],
        product_category_name:['Hard Drives'],
        product_subcategory_id:['414'],
        product_subcategory_name:['Desktop External Hard Drives'],
        product_id:['9SIA29P2YK5768'],
        product_web_id:['9SIA29P2YK5768'],
        product_title:['WD Elements 2TB USB 3.0 External Desktop Storage WDBWLG0020HBK-NESN Black'],
        product_manufacture:['Western Digital'],
        product_unit_price:['89.99'],
        product_sale_price:['79.99'],
        product_default_shipping_cost:['0.01'],
        product_type:['Seller'],
        product_model:['WDBWLG0020HBK-NESN'],
        product_instock:['1'],
        product_group_id:['30896206'],
        hl_seller_id_list:'A29P|A4P0|1|A6ZP|A2F8|A1N8|A24G|A0ZX|A8H5|A6AH',
        hl_prod_id_list:'9SIA29P2YK5768|9SIA4P02RJ6296|N82E16822236715|9SIA6ZP3K22742|9SIA2F83426160|9SIA1N81YB4387|9SIA24G2179173|9SIA0ZX1W07804|9SIA8H531C6923|9SIA6AH3AB2901',
        hl_prod_p_list:'79.99|89.99|94.99|106.62|109.35|110.29|109.59|113.93|131.86|131.69',
        hl_prod_qty_list:'1|1|1|1|1|1|1|1|1|1',
        parent_item:'N82E16822236715',
        page_type:'Product',
        site_region:'USA',
        site_currency:'USD',
        page_name:'ProductDetail',
        search_scope:jQuery('#haQuickSearchStore option:selected').text(),
        user_nvtc:Web.StateManager.Cookies.get(Web.StateManager.Cookies.Name.NVTC),
        user_name:Web.StateManager.Cookies.get(Web.StateManager.Cookies.Name.LOGIN,'LOGINID6'),
        third_party_render:['4774d6780334a7bf9c3c95255c60401916d07cae','78b8b16d9d0f6f2e8419ac12fa710f5153f1cee3','65531e14b4d9b9a223cc3bfcb65ce7b5f356011d','2a5e772a0f941c862180037f8a5c118c7abf2f7d','9011adc5233493f5adc5f0f0f1bcb655892c09e3']

  };
```

So if I were you, I would do a Regex which will take every digits and points (`[\d.]+`) between `product_sale_price:['` (`product_sale_price:\['`) and `']` (`'\]`)

So it is something like this :

```
product_sale_price:\['([\d.]+)'\]
```

So in PHP it would be :

```
$str = '...'; // The JS array OR the full HTML page will also work
preg_match("/product_sale_price:\['([\d.]+)'\]/", $str, $matches);
```

So your result would be stored inside the `$matches` array; so :

```
$price = floatval($matches[1]);
```

Comment: You're welcome ! Don't forget to mark the question as solved !